# How do I include a built-in django widget template in my custom widget template?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I am writing a Django widget in my app. However, as the widget is an extension of a `<textarea>` I would like to include within it the Django Textarea widget: `django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/textarea.html`.

I tried this:

```
<div name="{{ widget.name }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/textfield.html" %}>
    {% if widget.value %}{{ widget.value }}{% endif %}
</div>
```

However, it resulted in the following error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/myApp/myModel/add/
```

How should I refer the `include` statement to the proper template file?

Comment: because the `textfield.html` file doesn't exist.

Comment: Is `textfield.html` a typo when you actually tried `textarea.html` as written right above?

Comment: @RY is correct that your original reference to the built-in template was a typo and you wanted 'textarea.html' not 'textfield.html' -- also notice that you're <div> tag is still open when you include the body of 'textarea.html' which will give you an undesirable outcome.

Comment: Refunding my bounty because I don’t think the Stack Overflow community team will get to the request to invalidate the illegitimate votes on the current top answer in time, which is still scored +2 after my downvote.

Comment: You can award me :P as it is a *similar* answer to the top (illegitimate) voted post

Comment: Well it won't be no 500 reputation points, but when i get a free minute or two i will checkout the answers and accept the best one.

Answer (score 4):

You should add this setting on your Django's setting file:

```
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'
```

Refer to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/renderers/#templatessetting

So Django is able to find the built-in template file `{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}` and you get rid of the `TemplateDoesNotExist` error.

Don't forget to add `django.forms` in INSTALLED_APPS and at least one engine with APP_DIRS=True. Otherwise the exception continues.

Answer (score 2):

forms.py

```
from my_app.widgets import CustomTextArea
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    message = forms.CharField(max_length=500,widget=CustomTextArea(attrs={'cols': 10,'rows': 3,'class':'form-control'}),required=True,help_text=_('The max length of the text is 500.'))
```

widgets.py

```
from django import forms
class CustomTextArea(forms.Textarea):
    template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/textfield.html'
```

Please create `textfield.html` inside in templates folder in `my_app` with correct path if you required.I follow this location(`my_app/templates/django/forms/widgets/textfield.html`).You should must follow this when use this code.

textfield.html

**1st** method:Only show correct widget not altering in html.

```
{% include "django/forms/widgets/textarea.html" %}
{% if widget.value %}{{ widget.value }}{% endif %}
```

is equalent to:

```
<textarea name="{{ widget.name }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
{% if widget.value %}{{ widget.value }}{% endif %}</textarea>
```

**2nd** method: we can renders `<textarea>...</textarea>` as inside `div`.then,

```
<div>
  {% include "django/forms/widgets/textarea.html" %}
  {% if widget.value %}{{ widget.value }}{% endif %}
</div>
```

is equalent to:

```
    <div>
       <textarea name="{{ widget.name }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
       {% if widget.value %}{{ widget.value }}{% endif %}</textarea>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why the [`TemplateDoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.TemplateDoesNotExist) error?

Because Django tried to fetch the template named `textfield.html` in the [**`django/forms/widgets/`**](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets) directory, but, couldn't found.

> How do I include a built-in django widget template in my custom widget template?

Here, you want to create a [*custom `django.forms.Textarea`*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Textarea) widget. For that, you need to inherit the base class and then you should set **`template_name`** to some other custom value, which points towards the custom template.

```
# my_app/widget.py
from django import forms


class CustomTextArea(forms.Textarea):
    template_name = 'my_app/widget/custom_text_area.html'
```

```
# my_app/templates/my_app/widget/custom_text_area.html

<textarea name="{{ widget.name }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
{% if widget.value %}{{ widget.value }}{% endif %}</textarea>
```

---

Alternatively, you can set the **`<textarea>...</textarea>`** inside **`<div>...</div>`** tag as

```
<div class="{{ widget.name }}">
    <textarea name="{{ widget.name }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
        {% if widget.value %}{{ widget.value }}{% endif %}</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: `{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}` will fail for the same reason. (I think textfield.html in the question is a typo for textarea.html.)

Comment: maybe `textfield.html` was a typo, and hence the [`TemplateDoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.TemplateDoesNotExist) exception was raised.

Comment: Could you point out in which case the `{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}` might fail? @Ry-